# How to prevent package from being updated from other repo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have created a repository, where I will put own created packages and packages I don't want from other sources. E.g.

```
# apt-cache policy facter
facter:
  Installed: 1.7.2-1puppetlabs1
  Candidate: 1.7.2-1puppetlabs1
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.2-1puppetlabs1 0
        500 ftp://example.com/ ./ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.5-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

The problem is that Ubuntu also have a version of this particular package, and while my version is higher than Ubuntu's I don't suspect Ubuntu's to be installed. But what will happen when Ubuntu's are newer than mine? How do I prevent Ubuntu's from ever being installed, then the package is installed from my repo?

Comment: Not likely. Since you're using the official repo from Puppet Labs, it will always have the newest versions first.

Comment: The package is copied from the puppetlabs repo, but based on previous experiences with puppetlabs, I dare not to update to a newer version before I have tested it very carefully. So the puppetlabs repo is not on any of my hosts. That's why I mirror the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

To disable automatic updates from repository "your_repo"(from which you do not want the package to be automatically updated ever), add a file /etc/apt/preferences.d/your_repo with the following content:

```
Package: facter*
Pin: release n=repo
Pin-Priority: 50
```

This will give facter* packages from this repository a lower priority than already installed packages (which have 100).

Comment: I don't quite understand the priority concept from `man apt_preferences`, so just to be clear: If i replace `n=repo` with `n=precise` then the 12.04 packages will never get installed even if they are newer?

Comment: yes for that package from that repo they will never to get updated automatically, unless you will specifically do that with "-t" option.

Comment: Here:   If two or more versions have the same priority, install the most recent one (that is, the one with the higher version number). Since your precise repo will contain a lower priority for that package it will never gets installed even if it is a higher version number, unless you explicitly will tell "apt-get" to do so with "-t" option

Answer (score 1):

This is known as pinning. Ubuntu has some high-level documentation available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) which recommends reading a man page for further information about specific syntax for the configuration file in question.